# Laurent Series Question: Summation Starts from $-\infty$?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> Consider $f(z)=\frac{2z-4}{z^2-4z+3}$. Find the Laurent series for $f(z)$ that converges when $|z-1|>2$.

My working:

\begin{align}
f(z)&=\frac{1}{z-3}+\frac{1}{z-1} \\
&=\frac{1}{z-1}\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{z-1}}\right)+\frac{1}{z-1} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2^n}{(z-1)^{n+1}}\right)+\frac{1}{z-1}
\end{align}

Now, the answer provided is, $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} c_n(z-1)^n, \ \ c_{-1}=2 \ \text{and} \ c_n=2^{-n-1} \ \ n\leq -2.$$
I do not understand in the slightest why this is. What am I missing?

Comment: Unsure why there is a vote to close..

Answer (score 1):

$(z-1)^{-k}=\frac{1}{(z-1)^k}$; your answers seem the same up to indexing

Comment: When you say indexing, do you mean where my summation starts and finished?

Comment: Yes; they start the sum at $n=-1$ and have a power of $n$ on $(z-1)$. You start the sum at $n=0$ and have a power of $n+1$. (If there are too many $n$'s here to make this clear, make the substitution $i=n+1$ in your answer and change every $n$ you see to an $i$)

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand why their summation starts from $n=-\infty$. I have let $i=n+1$, which yields, $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2^{i-1}}{(z-1)^i}\right)+\frac{1}{z-1}.$$ Which is different from the answer provided

Comment: The indexing is done that way because since the powers are negative. $c_n$ is reduced to $b_n$ and by definition of Laurent series, the indexing is changed to $b_{-n}$ and the summation is from $-\infty$ to $-1$

Answer (score 0):

They are same. But there seem to be typos. It is $c_{-1}$ and $n\leq -2$.

Comment: Yep, I edited 6 mins ago :) thanks for the spot